# The error code is related with the cv2.absdiff to find the different between two images

Tags: python

I had an error code to find the difference between two images as below

error: OpenCV(4.5.5-dev) C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\opencv\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:650: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'

to find the solution

Comment: You would need to post a [mre] for us to help you fix the error, but it says right there "Sizes of input arguments do not match". That should tell you where to look.